# Get coordinates for (id)sender (iOS)

Tags: xcode, ibaction, coordinate

I have a program, where there are a bunch of buttons, and I would like to make an action, so you get the coordinates for the button that has been pushed, but without making an action for each everyone.
I figured, that you could somehow get the coordinates from the (id)sender in an action, but I dont know how.

Answer (score 2):

This action method tests if the sender is derived from `UIControl` (so it can safely cast the `id` to `UIControl *`) and displays the control's `frame`:

```
- (void)myAction:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isMemberOfClass:[UIControl class]])
    {
        UIControl *control = (UIControl *)sender;
        NSLog(@"control frame=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(control.frame));
    }
}
```